# clearInterval when object is no longer referenced?

Tags: javascript, typescript, clearinterval

I have a class that acts as a client to a server (through a WebSocket). I would like to implement a system that periodically pings the server to determine latency. However, I am concerned that if I use `setInterval` inside the class for this purpose, it will continue to try to ping after the object should be garbage collected. How can I know when to call `clearInterval`?

Summary of code:

```
class WSClient extends EventEmitter
{
    private latency: number;
    public get Latency(): number
    { return this.latency; }

    public async ping(): Promise<number>
    { ... }

    public constructor(options)
    {
        super();

        // Do constructor stuff

        setInterval(() => this.ping().then(latency => this.latency = latency), 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a recursive `setTimeout()` conditionally based on `if(obj){}`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's a very good idea. So the object should still be garbage collected even if I am referencing it in the callback? (`if (obj) { ... }`)

Comment: We'd need to see your code structure to be able to answer that.

Comment: Probably not as the object is still referenced. Maybe you could implement a `destroy` method that clears the interval.

Comment: @muecas It depends on whether all this code is in a single invocation context or not.

Comment: It's quite a large class, so I'll try to include only the important parts.

Comment: @ScottMarcus and it will depend on the browser too, they all have different “ideas” on when something should be collected for garbage.

Comment: @muecas That's an implementation detail that really isn't important. What matters is if any new code affects the object's ability to be garbage collected, not the collection itself.

Comment: Please see the code I posted.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen When will the object be garbage collected? You cannot get around manually destructing the interval. Usually there is some kind of `end` or `close` event for when the socket expires - that's when you should clear your interval.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with classes

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval() and save it to an variable, then you can access that interval like so:

```
class WSClient extends EventEmitter
{
    private latency: number;
    public get Latency(): number
    { return this.latency; }

    public async ping(): Promise<number>
    { ... }

    public constructor(options)
    {
        super();

        // Do constructor stuff

        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.ping()
        .then(latency => this.latency = latency), 1000);
    }
}
```

Then when you need:

```
WSClient.interval.clearInterval();
```

Comment: You should call when it fails after too long, but when it failed for too long depends on your configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing: you'll never reach a point where the object "should" be garbage collected, because the `setInterval` you've defined is holding a reference to that object (in your context, as `this`) in perpetuity. You're going to need some extra logic to determine if you still need to run it.

What I'd recommend, and it's an easy approach since you've already defined your `get Latency()`, is to put some logic in there to monitor if anyone's actually asked for the latency in a while. If the getter's been run recently, keep polling. If it hasn't, remove the interval.

You could make this much easier if you defined, instead, `async getLatency()`, that way if you detect that the latency hasn't been recently pinged, you can wait until the latency is recalculated.

I haven't run this, but am including it to illustrate the idea:

```
// ms to wait until cancelling the interval
const latencyTimeout = 200000;

// In your class

async getLatency(): number {
  if (!this.latency) {
    const started = Date.now();
    const poller = setInterval(async () => {
       if (Date.now() - started > latencyTimeout) {
         clearInterval(poller);
         this.latency = null;
       }
       this.latency = await this.ping();
    }, 1000);
    this.latency = await this.ping();
  }
  return this.latency;
}
```

As an aside, you may want to consider not using the `setInterval`, but a recurring `setTimeout` instead. The problem with the interval, is that it's based on its own clock. It won't take into account the amount of time needed to complete the ping. eg if you're polling every second, but it takes 500ms to complete the ping, it'll be okay, but if it takes 2000ms to ping then your pings will actually go out of order. It could look like you have a much slower ping, because you're receiving the return from a ping that took longer than a recent one that ran fast. Better to do a `setTimeout` instead that only runs after the last one completed.